# React js, redux consume api

Tags: reactjs, redux

Well I'm studying redux, but I was a little doubt how best to consume the api

i have on app:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/HomePage';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
      <Home/>
      </Provider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

my

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
export default class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

function reducer(){
    return [

    ];
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

I am wondering where I would put my communication with my api

would it be an action?

Comment: This will likely be opinion-based, but I prefer doing it in asynchronous action creators, using a `thunk` middleware to be able to dispatch actions asynchronously

Comment: Could you make an example based on what I posted so that I vote positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using "redux-thunk". First, add thunk to your store and than You can put your API call inside the action creator :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you give me an example regarding this code I posted?

Comment: Take a look here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250036/where-to-put-api-calls-in-react-redux-architecture
It's a really good source of knowledge and there's even an example of how to to this

Answer (score -1):

Use Redux-Saga for this.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

From doc:

> redux-saga is a library that aims to make application side effects
>   (i.e. asynchronous things **like data fetching** and impure things like
>   accessing the browser cache) easier to manage, more efficient to
>   execute, easy to test, and better at handling failures.

Comment: Isn't that an overkill ?

Comment: For hello world app yes it is.